# iOS AppDelegate crashes when adding didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have the following App delegate for an iOS app in Xcode 8.3:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  }
}
```

When I start my app in either the simulator or on a device, it crashes with the following message:

```
2017-07-04 21:26:04.284336+0200 MyApp[352:25788] -[NSTaggedPointerString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00000070696f764
2017-07-04 21:26:04.284569+0200 MyApp[352:25788] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [NSTaggedPointerString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to  instance 0xa00000070696f764'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x188baefe0 0x187610538 0x188bb5ef4 0x188bb2f54 0x188aaed4c 0x18ef7d030 0x18ef630f4 0x18ef77d18 0x18ef60474 0x18a757884 0x18a7576f0 0x18a757aa0 0x188b5d42c 0x188b5cd9c 0x188b5a9a8 0x188a8ada4 0x18ed4a384 0x18ed45058 0x100106fc8 0x187a9959c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

In the simulator, it's a slightly different error message:

```
2017-07-04 21:30:10.379 MyApp[55965:1127208] -[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000028d60
2017-07-04 21:30:10.383 MyApp[55965:1127208] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000028d60'
```

Removing the `application(:didReceiveRemoteNotification)` method makes the crash disappear.

Does anyone have any clue what's going on?

Comment: The error message says somewhere a string is passed where a collection type is expected.

Comment: You didnt post complete code. Crash must be happening inside didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: @adev This is the entire code of AppDelegate (yes, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is empty, and it still crashes).

Comment: had you removed func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the problem: my `Info.plist` had 'Background Modes' set to a string instead of an array of modes. Fixing that fixes the crash.

Comment: Thanks! This was crashing my expo app. Adding the string in an array for the ‘’UIBackgroundModes’ field in ’app.json’ fixed the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a third party framework that's causing the issue here. For one, you've posted Swift code, but are getting an Objective-C error message. It's likely that a library you're using is registering itself to handle notifications.

Second, the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` needs to always call it's `completionHandler` before exiting. So a blank function will cause issues.

You need to call `completionHandler` with a parameter of either `.newData`, `.noData`, or `.failed` depending on your results.